# How to count the number of checkboxes selected in Infopath?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath2010

I have a column in a SharePoint List of type "Choice" - it's a collection of Checkboxes. I need to add an action in Infopath where the number of Checkboxes that are selected is assigned to another variable. How can I get the number of checkboxes that are selected?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

have you tried creating a field in your infopath form that is set on open to be the sum of whatever your checkbox value conditions are? So for instance you would do several checks for values and where the condition is met increment your counter by 1 by using the set value for field action.